# Touch functionality is not working in portrait mode with ubuntu-20.04.2.0

Tags: display, touchscreen

I deployed ubuntu-20.04.2.0 on NUC10 hardware from Intel and connected this mini PC with portrait screen. When we changed display orientation to portrait then display is showing portrait but touch is not working. It looks like there is no support for portrait touch in display driver.

Is there any solution for this without doing calibration?